# c# - StreamWriter Issue when adding Date to the filename

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm having a small issue with the `System.IO.StreamWriter`.

```
StreamWriter Write = 
   new StreamWriter(@"../Debug/Payments/_" + dp.Value.ToString() + ".txt");
```

**When I run the application, it returns:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: dp.value.ToString() is a datePicker

Comment: No, it's still returning the same error

Comment: Sorry, i've solved the issue. The format was unacceptable

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string filename= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd");
string strpath = Server.MapPath("~/Debug/Payments/_"+ filename + ".txt");
StreamWriter Write = new StreamWriter(strpath);
```

Your problem is with the format.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say `dp` is a datepicker, the `ToString()` is almost certainly going to be inserting invalid characters like `:` into the file name, e.g.

```
Payments/_2017/11/13 1:14:13 PM.txt
```

Also, as per the comments, you'll need to change the slash direction.

You'll need to use a safer date format, like so:

```
$@"..\Debug\Payments\_{dp.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks guys! Haha i just realised it!